# Why is $\log(n) \approx \log(N)$ for most $n$ in the range $[1,N]$?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

In several probabilistic models of prime numbers, the following approximation is used:

$$ \log(n) \approx \log(N) $$

where integer $n$ runs from $1$ to $N$ in sums or integrals.

The explanation (usually not given) seems to be that for most $n$ in that range, $\log(n) \approx \log(N)$ because the logarithm is, to quote, a "flattening function".

I don't understand this as $\log()$ is not flattening like $\tanh()$, for example.

**Question:** Why is the approximation is valid?

Comment: To quote what? If you have a problem with some books or papers, it's a good idea to give citations to provide context.

Comment: A first idea: Consider X equally distributed on $[0, N]$. Compute the expected value of $\log(N) - \log(X) = \log(N / X)$, i. e. the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\log(N / n)\frac{1}{N} = \dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $n = N/2$. You have, $\log(n) = \log(N/2) = \log(N) - \log(2) = \log(N) - 0.6931$

Let's say you want $\log(N/2)$ to be 90% of $\log(N)$ (just as an illustration). Easy to see from the above equation that $N>1024$ will satisfy this requirement. So, for an $N>1024$, $\log(n)$ is within 90% of $\log(N) \; \forall \; n>N/2$, i.e. $\log(n) \approx \log(N)$ for half the range.

Of course, the $n$ and $N$ over which the approximation holds depends on the accuracy you desire, which in turn depends on your application.

Answer (score 3):

If $N/e < n < N$, then $\log(N)-1 < \log(n) < \log(N)$; i.e. $\log(n)$ is within 1 of $\log(N)$.  This is true for $63\%$ (i.e. $1 - 1/e$) of numbers in $[1, N]$.  You can get higher percentages than this by replacing $N/e$ with $N/e^2$, etc.

For example:  say $N \approx e^{1000000}$, so $\log(n) \approx 1000000$.  You would probably agree that any number between $999000$ and $1000000$ is "approximately $1000000$".  But $\log(n)$ is in this range whenever we have
$$e^{999000} < n < e^{1000000} \approx N.$$
Since
$$\frac{e^{1000000}}{e^{999000}} = e^{1000} \approx 2 \cdot 10^{434},$$
the interval $[e^{999000}, e^{1000000}]$ takes up about $99.999...95\%$ of the interval $[1, N]$, where there are 434 nines in total.